# Query local JSON File in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have a local JSON file that I am trying to parse based on a value. I can correctly get all the values from the file but what's the best solution to get a particular value. let say i have the following JSON data

```
[{ "city" : "AGAWAM", "loc" : [ -72.622739, 42.070206 ], "pop" : 15338, 
"state" : "MA", "_id" : "01001" }

, { "city" : "CUSHMAN", "loc" : [ -72.51564999999999, 42.377017 ], 
"pop" 
: 36963, "state" : "MA", "_id" : "01002" }

, { "city" : "BARRE", "loc" : [ -72.10835400000001, 42.409698 ], "pop" 
: 4546, "state" : "MA", "_id" : "01005" }]
```

Say I only want to show line with _id = 01002. What would be the best solution to achieve what I am asking? I added what I already have, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "zip", withExtension: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            let jsonRecord = json["_id"]
            print("this is json \(jsonRecord)")

        } catch {
            // handle error
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

found my answer using different terminology

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33044822/1572452/)

Swift array version:

```
let peopleNamedTom = arrayOfPeople.filter { $0["Name"] == "Tom" }
```

SwiftyJSON array version:

```
let peopleNamedTom = arrayOfPeople.filter { $1["Name"] == "Tom" }
```